# How can I grantPermission on iroha with android?

Tags: android, hyperledger

I got some code for grantPermission from iOS in iroha as below:

```
func getGrantPermission(publicKey :String,priKey:String, transaction: IRTransaction, reducedRecoveryHash: 
        Data, reducedAdminGrantHash: Data) throws -> IRTransaction  {
        let publicKeyData = NSData(hexString: publicKey)! as Data
        let publicKey = IREd25519PublicKey(rawData: publicKeyData)!

        let privateKeyData = NSData(hexString: priKey)! as Data
        let privateKey = IREd25519PrivateKey(rawData: privateKeyData)!
        let signer = IREd25519Sha512Signer(privateKey: privateKey)!

        let reducedHash = try transaction.batchHash()
        let tx = try transaction
                    .batched([reducedHash, reducedRecoveryHash, reducedAdminGrantHash], batchType: .atomic)
                   .signed(withSignatories: [signer], signatoryPublicKeys: [publicKey])

   return tx
 }
```

How can I write this function in android. I am very struggle with this case.

Comment: grant Permission for what?

Comment: for iroha hyperledger